# Scattering panda dtype objects

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot, data-science

I'm trying to create a scatter plot using latitude and longitude data sets.

The code I have is this:

```
raw = pd.read_csv('locations.csv')
latitude = raw['LATITUDE'].values
longitude = raw['LONGITUDE'].values
plt.scatter(latitude, longitude)
```

But I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: nan is not a string
```

Is this because I have NaN values in the datasets?

I'd appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even with random data that altered both columns to string (i.e., object) and randomly assigned NaNs, I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: Are you sure the rest of your values (not the NaN's) aren't strings? I see they have a direction appended...